# Calling functions on Root ViewController from within a child SKScene

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, iad

I have a UIViewController class called "ViewController" and it accesses several SKScenes.

I have these two functions to present and hide ads:

```
-(void)showBannerView{
    if (_adBanner && !_adBannerViewIsVisible){
        _adBannerViewIsVisible = true;

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

        CGRect frame = _adBanner.frame;
        frame.origin.x = 0.0f;
        frame.origin.y = 0.0f;

        _adBanner.frame = frame;

        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}

-(void)hideBannerView{
    if (_adBanner && _adBannerViewIsVisible){
        _adBannerViewIsVisible = false;

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

        CGRect frame = _adBanner.frame;
        frame.origin.x = 0.0f;
        frame.origin.y = -_adBanner.frame.size.height ;

        _adBanner.frame = frame;

        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }

}
```

The only remaining thing I need to figure out is how to call these functions on the correct parent ViewController.

How can I go about doing this from within one of my SKScenes?

I've tried (from within the skscene):

```
[self.view.window.rootViewController hideBannerView];
[self.view.window.rootViewController showBannerView];
```

and

```
ViewController *parent = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[parent hideBannerView];
```

The first one just throws an error, and the parent code just doesn't do anything because it's creating another view controller rather than accessing the given one.

I also tried making a property on the skscene of type 'ViewController *' and it didn't let me access the property from the viewcontroller (I was trying to set the property equal to 'self', effectively referencing the viewcontroller from the skscene)

Comment: have tried something or not?  maybe it's like calling a method from another view controller? ignoring the fact that it is a SKScene

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely familiar with spriteKit, but I think this should work just the same.

In RootViewController.h in viewDidLoad add:

```
// Note Notification name:  you should probably use a constant
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(updateBannerView:)
                                             name:@"kNotificationUpdateBannerView"
                                           object:nil];
```

Then, still in RootViewController.h add:

```
- (void) updateBannerView:(NSNotification *)note {
    NSDictionary * info = note.userInfo;
    BOOL shouldHide = [info[@"shouldHide"]boolValue];

    if (shouldHide) {
        NSLog(@"shouldHide");
        [self hideBannerView];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"shouldShow");
        [self showBannerView];
    }
}
```

Now, you're all set up.  Whenever you want to call it, use this:

```
BOOL shouldHide = YES; // whether or not to hide

// Update Here!
NSDictionary * dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:shouldHide], @"shouldHide", nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"kNotificationUpdateBannerView" // Better as constant!
                                                   object:self 
                                                 userInfo:dict];
```

Now, wherever you are in your app, you can hide/show your banner ads!

Comment: I set everything up but sill the ad banner wont hide, first the BOOl isn't getting changed in the dictionary, but even when it is manually set, my hide banner function does nothing. Is there something wrong with that part of the code?

Comment: I just found it, sorry.  When I copied onto here, I set up the dictionary wrong.  Values come before keys.  See Update.